# what does perl operator "||=" do?

Tags: perl

What does the operator `||=` do in perl?

to be more specific if you have a code like:

```
my ($my_link);
$my_link  ||= DownloadF($file,'l') if $s->{_l};
$my_link  ||= DownloadF($file,'h') if $s->{_h};
$my_link  ||= DownloadF($file,'o') if $s->{_o};
```

what is `||=` suppose to do and what is the difference between `||=` and a simple `=`?

Comment: Try [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl supports lots of assignment operators.  `||=` is just a `logical or` (complete with shortcircuit,) assignment.

So essentially what you're looking at is:

```
if ($s->{_l}) {
  $my_link = $my_link || DownloadF($file,'l');
}
```

So if `$my_link` evaluates to some true value then `$my_link` will be assigned to itself (a no-op essentially), otherwise the result of `DownloadF` is assigned.

Other assignment operators supported by perl:

```
 **= += *= &= <<= &&=
-= /= |= >>= ||=
.= %= ^= //=
x=
```

Comment: It appears to be used in this case so that each of the _possible_ assignments used the same pattern of operators.

Answer (score 2):

If `$my_link` is false `(empty string, 0 or undef)` store `DownloadF($file,'l')` into `$my_link`

This construct has always had problems when used to assign a default value (what if you want `$my_link` to be zero)

Answer (score 1):

it means if $my_link is nil/has no value, then assign it this value with = (value)

if $my_link already has a value, then it don't do anything

Answer (score 1):

It assigns only if variable evaluates to false value.
In each of your example lines, `$my_link` will only be assigned if the condition `$s->{..}` is true.